# Order query and OrderDetail

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, ado.net, shopping-cart

**Order Table**

```
OrderId
CustomerId
Date
Total
```

**OrderDetails**

```
OrderDetailId
OrderId
ProductId
Quantity
UnitPrice
```

i am using Order query

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Orders (CustomerId, Date, Total)
VALUES (1, 2011-04-10, 50000);
```

I am executing OrderDetail query many times.

```
DECLARE @OrderID int
SET @OrderID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetail (OrderId,ProductDescriptionId,Quantity,UnitPrice)
VALUES (@OrderID,11,2,50000)
```

The problem here is that the value of @OrderID changes, and no longer matches the foreign key from the Orders table after i execute this query for the second time. so what should i do to fix this?

Comment: Are you calling everything from DECLARE to VALUES the second time?  Or just the 2nd Insert?

Comment: everything from declare to values.....why is it wrong? if i call it from inset to values..i get an error saying @OrderId is not declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I.` You have to use the ***same connection*** to:

Insert the Order:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Orders (CustomerId, Date, Total)
VALUES (1, 2011-04-10, 50000);
```

Retrieve `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and store it in some place in your code (you havn't supplied the .NET code, so I could give you more precise advice) :

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
int lastOrderId = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

`II.` Then (same connection or not):

Insert OrderDetails using:

-- concatenation:

```
"INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetail (OrderId,ProductDescriptionId,Quantity,UnitPrice)
 VALUES ('" + lastOrderId.ToString() + "',11,2,50000)"
```

-- or [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx):

```
command.Parameters.Add("@OrderID", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters("@OrderID").Value = lastOrderId;

INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetail (OrderId,ProductDescriptionId,Quantity,UnitPrice)
VALUES (@OrderID,11,2,50000)
```

Comment: are you sure command.ExecuteScalar takes in 1 argument?
I am getting this error
No overload for method 'ExecuteScalar' takes 1

Comment: no of course ;) i fixed the code (doc here *http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx*)

Answer (score 1):

If your order detail as an identity field, then when you call INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetail it's going to change SCOPE_IDENTITY.  You'd need to set or @OrderID once for each Order entry and not call SCOPE_IDENTITY again until you've added another column to your Orders table.

```
--Run this once per order
INSERT INTO dbo.Orders (CustomerId, Date, Total)
VALUES (1, 2011-04-10, 50000);

--Run this once per order
DECLARE @OrderID int
SET @OrderID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

--Run this once per orderdetail
INSERT INTO dbo.OrderDetail (OrderId,ProductDescriptionId,Quantity,UnitPrice)
VALUES (@OrderID,11,2,50000)
```

Comment: Thats what i have been trying to do, its just that it gives the error, you must declare @OrderId.